# How to find the coordinates of a point such that it makes a 135 degree angle with a given line?

Tags: python, geometry, trigonometry

Given a line segment `uv` I want to find the coordinates of point `x` such that they make up an angle of 135 degrees with a given distance of `L`, below is an illustration:

[image: Sample]

Comment: How is your line segment formatted?

Comment: This is a simple problem if you understand how vectors work: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: @duffymo nothing about that wikipedia article looks simple :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `uv` vector as

```
uv.x = v.x - u.x
uv.y = v.y - u.y
```

Calculate its length

```
luv = sqrt(uv.x * uv.x + uv.y * uv.y)
```

Find point at continuation of `uv` line with distance `L` from `v`:

```
px = v.x + L * uv.x  / luv
py = v.y + L * uv.y  / luv
```

Rotate this point around `v` by 45 degrees (`Pi/4`):

```
qx = v.x + (p.x - v.x) * cos(Pi/4) - (p.y - v.y) * sin(Pi/4)
qy = v.y + (p.x - v.x) * sin(Pi/4) + (p.y - v.y) * cos(Pi/4)
```

Note that we can simplify tha last expressions a bit using coordinate difference

```
rx = L * uv.x  / luv
ry = L * uv.y  / luv
```

Rotate this point around `v` by 45 degrees (`Pi/4`):

```
qx = v.x + rx * cos(Pi/4) - ry * sin(Pi/4)
qy = v.y + rx * sin(Pi/4) + ry * cos(Pi/4)
```

Also both `cos(Pi/4)` and `sin(Pi/4)` are equal to `sqrt(2)/2`, so you can use this constant if you don't need different angles.

Comment: Does this also work for diagonal line segments or only straight lines parallel to `x` axis? Because I'm getting `(2.0, 4.0)` for `u=(3.0, 3.0) v=(2.0, 2.0) length=2`.

Comment: Yes, It works for any segment angle.  `qy = 2 + (-2/sqrt(2) * sqrt(2)/2) + (-2/sqrt(2) * sqrt(2)/2) = 0`, not 4

Comment: Okay this is working, but I'm confused which numbers are the variables, my bad I set the `v=(2,2)` and `L=2` and now there are too many 2's :D . I replaced the `cos` and `sin` with `sqrt(2)/2` but I'm still getting 4 as the result! Here's my implemenation: `qy = vy + (px - vx) * (math.sqrt(2) / 2) + (py - vy) * (math.sqrt(2) / 2)`

Comment: note that uv in your case has negative components, so px = 2 **-** 1*2 / (sqrt(2)), same for py

Answer (score 1):

I would use a triangle to determine where x is, you can use a 45 45 90 triangle because the angle is 135 degrees. If it was not 135 degrees you can use sin and cos to find x

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't have to calculate all the math by yourself. There are several libraries for geometric computation that offer functionality to perform the task in just a couple of lines of code.

For example, [Shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html) has [`rotate`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.affinity.rotate) and [`scale`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.affinity.scale) functions that could be used here:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
from shapely.affinity import rotate, scale

uv = LineString([(0, 0), (1, 0)])
vx_length = 2
pivot_point = uv.boundary[1]
scale_factor = vx_length / uv.length
uv_rotated = rotate(uv, -135, origin=pivot_point)
vx = scale(uv_rotated, 
           xfact=scale_factor,
           yfact=scale_factor,
           origin=pivot_point)
print(vx)
# LINESTRING (2.414213562373095 1.414213562373095, 1 0)
print(vx.length)
# 2.0
```

[image]

Note that we should give the negative angle to `rotate` since by default rotation is performed counterclokwise but we need it to be clockwise.